# All England wins for Lee Chong Wei?

Tags: trivia, tournaments, badminton

How many times has Lee Chong Wei won the men's singles in the All England Badminton Championships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lee Chong Wei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Chong_Wei) just won his third championship against [Chen Long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_Long):

- [BWF broadcast of the MSF](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbohDcd4yIs)

Reference:

- [List of All England Men's Singles champions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_All_England_Men%27s_Singles_champions)